# Xen in routed mode: start fails

Tags: debian, xen

When Xen is configured in routed mode, restarting xend fails because the script hotplugpath.sh is missing.

```
~ # /etc/init.d/xend restart
Restarting Xen daemons: xend/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
 xend/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
.
```

I'm using Debian Squeeze and XEN 4.0

Any idea?

Comment: Was manually creating the hotplugpath.sh the only change you made to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a packaging bug. It can be worked around by install `xen-utils-common` from testing, or else creating the file by hand:

```
$ cat /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh 
SBINDIR="/usr/sbin"
BINDIR="/usr/bin"
LIBEXEC="/usr/lib/xen/bin"
LIBDIR="/usr/lib64"
SHAREDIR="/usr/share"
PRIVATE_BINDIR="/usr/lib64/xen/bin"
XENFIRMWAREDIR="/usr/lib/xen/boot"
XEN_CONFIG_DIR="/etc/xen"
XEN_SCRIPT_DIR="/etc/xen/scripts"
XEN_LOCK_DIR="/var/lock"
```