# Network Script broken with recent XEN update in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, xen

Today I applied the most recent [xen](http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/xen) update for Debian Squeeze from [Security]. The package version is now `4.0.1-5.8`.

After that, xend began to behave weird (aka. wrong):

```
root@root:~# sudo service xend restart
Restarting Xen daemons: xend/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
 xend/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 20: /etc/xen/scripts/hotplugpath.sh: No such file or directory
/etc/xen/scripts/network-route: line 28: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp: No such file or directory
```

It worked before without any error, hence my question: Is this a bug or is it my fault?

Btw, I'm shure I did not change something around xen, i.e. not the `xend-config.sxp` or any of the scripts in `/etc/xen/scripts`. That's why I take [this old question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/411102/xen-in-routed-mode-start-fails) for unrelated, or at least only related in the manner that the package is incomplete again, as it was at that time according to only answer. (Which in turn would be a bug, right?)

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth/proxy_arp` this is a kernel IPv4 setting not directly related to xen. It should exist...

Comment: Well it does, the script just does not get it that the interface is called `eth0`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Xen wiki](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XenNetworking#Setting_up_routing_on_the_host) the script `network-route` should not be used anymore starting with `Xen 4.1`. Unfortunately I'm on `Xen 4.0`, but I figured what has to be done manual in the next version can I configure manually already.

This means, on `ifup eth0` I trigger `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp`:

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 1.1.1.1
    broadcast 1.1.1.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 1.1.1.254

    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
```

And in `/etc/sysctl.conf` I set `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`.

That is pretty much what the `/etc/xen/scripts/network-route` would have done.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you not use bridging? I always refrain from activating ip_forwarding. This could turn your box into a router without wanting it - the network-guys do not like that very much...

Comment: Because my hoster does now allow it

Comment: He does not allow multiple MACs on one interface? This is something I would understand.

Comment: That's right, he doesn't.